# PowerShell : Copy-Item unique files from directory

Tags: powershell, copy-item

I have files in my directory : `Fa.txt`, `Fb.txt`, `Fc.txt`, `Fd.txt`, `Fd.lck`.

I want to copy unique file `Fa.txt`, `Fb.txt` and `Fc.txt` into a other directory

Here is my command :

```
Get-ChildItem c:\temp -Filter F*.* | Group-Object {$_.BaseName} | Where-Object{ 
$_.Count -lt 2} | Select-Object Name | ForEach-Object { Copy-Item c:\temp\$_ 
c:\temp\old}
```

I receive this error :

> Copy-Item : Cannot find path C:\temp\@{Name=Fa} because it does not exist.

Of course I see it's missing extension `.txt`. I tried with `c:\temp\$_.txt`.
I receive this error Copy-Item :

> Cannot find path `C:\temp\@{Name=Fc}.txt`, because it does not exist.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick fix:

```powershell
Get-ChildItem c:\temp -Filter F*.* | Group-Object {$_.BaseName} | Where-Object{ 
    $_.Count -lt 2} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name | ForEach-Object { 
    Copy-Item c:\temp\$_ c:\temp\old}
```